# How to cut sentence into words and list the index of each word?

Tags: php, string

I really need help. I'm really sorry because I'm a beginner in PHP coding.
I want to cut each word in a sentence, and list the index of each word.

Example sentence:

```
I want buy a new shoes this weekend.
```

I want my output like this:

```
[0] I , [1] want, [2] buy, [3] a, [4] new, [5] shoes, [6] this, [7] weekend
```

How would I accomplish this in PHP?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Comment: please check this php function http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this responds to your question

```
print_r(explode(" ", "I want buy a new shoes this weekend."));

Array
(
    [0] => I
    [1] => want
    [2] => buy
    [3] => a
    [4] => new
    [5] => shoes
    [6] => this
    [7] => weekend.
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use php split()

```
$text = "I want buy a new shoes this weekend";
$words = explode(" ", $text);
print_r($words);
```

This will give the following output.

```
Array
(
[0] => I
[1] => want
[2] => buy
[3] => a
[4] => new
[5] => shoes
[6] => this
[7] => weekend
```

)